# How to remove dashes from addLegend in leaflet R

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

I am using addLegend() in leaflet in R. My labels have minus signs in them. Is there an easy way to remove the dashes that come with numeric colour palettes to improve the formatting? labFormat doesn't seem to have such an option.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXbqJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you take a look at `addLegendNumeric` in the `leaflegend` package ? It has the option to set `tickWidth = 0` and `tickLength=0` which make dashes (tickmarks) disappear.

You can read about `leaflegend` here:
https://roh.engineering/posts/2021/02/introduction-to-leaflegend/

In the example for `addLegendNumeric` the author didn't include these two parameters, but you can try them for yourself.

Example code:

```
library(leaflet)

data(quakes)

# Numeric Legend

numPal <- colorNumeric('viridis', quakes$depth)
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addLegendNumeric(
    pal = numPal,
    values = quakes$depth,
    position = 'topright',
    tickLength = 0,
    tickWidth = 0,
    title = htmltools::tags$div('addLegendNumeric (Decreasing)',
                                style = 'font-size: 24px; text-align: center; margin-bottom: 5px;'),
    orientation = 'vertical',
    shape = 'stadium',
    decreasing = TRUE,
    height = 100,
    width = 20,
    bins = 4)
```

[image on quakes dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9wTv.png)